# Quasar Tree Shaking with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using Vue 3 + TS + Webpack, from a standard Vue + Webpack (no Vue CLI).

I did install Quasar as the following:

Added quasar and @quasar/extra as dependencies

```
//main.ts

app.use(Quasar, {
      plugins: {
        Loading,
        Notify,
      },
      config: {
        loading: {},
        notify: {},
      },
    });
```

But the bundle got huge and the project is already far advanced.
How can I tree shake it?